# How to get flattened list from dictionary key query where values are lists?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am trying to create an event/messaging system where the subscribers can subscribe to general event types or specific event types.

I have a dictionary of event types containing lists of subscribers of said types, and, for notifying the events to the subscribers, I want to get a flattened list of all subscriptions within those lists, where the subscription is of a type that is equal to or assignable from the event's type; in other words, when the dictionary key meets that as a criteria.

How do I get a flattened list of the items of lists queried from a dictionary's keys (using linq)?

---

My WIP code:

```
private Dictionary<Type, List<SomeEventDelegate>> subscriptions;

// ...other code...

public void Dispatch(SomeEvent someEvent)
    {
        // This should get the Key-Value pairs... How do I get a flattened list of all items in the values (which are lists themselves)?
        List<SomeEventDelegate> subscribers =
            from subscription in subscriptions
            where subscription.Key.IsAssignableFrom(someEvent.GetType())
            select subscription;

        //After I have the flattened list, I will dispatch the event to each subscriber here, in a foreach loop.
    }
```

Comment: On a side note, I don't think you should be doing this at all.  You don't need to manage the subscribers like that, that's built into delegates and events. If you need more control, there are frameworks built around this that gets it right.

Comment: @JeffMercado  For my specific needs, the subscribers need to be agnostic of the event-source objects, and must only know about the event types for the purpose of subscribing to those events. (They might receive a reference to the triggering/source object, depending on the event type; but that's not necessary or guaranteed overall) --- However, I am new to C# events, and might be missing critical information that may influence or completely change this requirement or my implementation. If you strongly suspect that to be the case, please do call me on chat to discuss further! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) should do the job:

```
List<SomeEventDelegate> subscribers =
    subscriptions.Where(kvp => 
        kvp.Key.IsAssignableFrom(someEvent.GetType())
    ).SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .ToList();
```

You can only do it with the chained-method-call syntax. You pass it a lambda that selects an `IEnumerable<T>` from the parameter, and as it goes it merges all the enumerables that it collects from each item in the query into one big flat query, which it returns.

Comment: Was lacking `as List<SomeEventDelegate>` at the end of the chain, but other than that, works *perfectly*! Many thanks Ed! =)

Comment: @AlmightyR Whoops! I think plain ToList() oughta do it, since Value is `IEnumerable<SomeEventDelegate>`.

Comment: Even better! =) --- (And yes, I'm very new to using linq...)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the query syntax (hence don't bother what exact method is used), why don't you just continue your query:

```
   List<SomeEventDelegate> subscribers =
        (from subscription in subscriptions
         where subscription.Key.IsAssignableFrom(someEvent.GetType())
         from subscriber in subscription.Value
         select subscriber)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: While this would maintain the syntax style of my original code, it's not as readable as Ed's answer's solution (IMO). Still, a +1 is deserved for the alternative.